# How do I instantiate an object without assigning a variable to it

Tags: python

I have a class, whose `__init__` function does a bunch of stuff, and that's all I need.

So I really just want to call the `__init__` function of this class. How can I do this, without assigning it to a variable?

Comment: First, the `__init__` function of a class doesn't really return a value. Second, why would you want to do this? If you're having this sort of problem, I'd say you're doing something wrong.

Comment: So, why do you need a class? A function could be simpler...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, this is clearly a design error - that code should just be a standalone function.

However, there are a couple of ways that you can do this:

1. Just instantiate as normal - there is no reason you have to assign the result of an expression to a variable. However, this will result in full object construction (and probably destruction shortly thereafter).

   ```
   Foo()
   ```
2. Call the underlying function:

   ```
   Foo.__dict__.get('__init__')(None)
   ```

This won't trigger object construction, but you probably don't want that. Note that in the example here, I've passed `None` as the value of `self`. This only works if `__init__` does nothing with `self` (or, handles the case where it is `None`).

2a. You could use staticmethod to make this easier:

```
In [32]: class Foo(object):
   ....:     @staticmethod
   ....:     def __init__():
   ....:         print "Foo init"
   ....:

In [33]: Foo()
Foo init
Out[33]: <django.core.management.commands.shell.Foo at 0x46d49b0>

In [34]: Foo.__init__()
Foo init
```

Comment: Will the second option work?  Don't you need to pass an instance to `Foo.__init__()`?  (e.g. `Foo.__init__(Foo())` ... Yuck.)

Comment: @mgilson Good point. I was confused about when functions are wrapped into methods.

Comment: keep in mind objects instantiated without reference counters will be garbage collected as soon as you leave the scope you called it from

Comment: @JoranBeasley That behaviour is not guaranteed.

Comment: It might be a little more clean if you decorated `__init__` with `@staticmethod` ... But, I don't have any idea why you would make this a class.  Trying to make this pretty is probably a waste of time.

Comment: may not be guaranteed but its been consistent in any tests I have done...  basically without refs I guess you cant guarantee lifetime at all ... but in my experience once you leave your scope that instance is destroyed

Comment: @JoranBeasley So, you're relying on your code working only a single version of a single implementation of Python. Not everyone uses the same exact interpreter you are.

Comment: all im saying is dont count on ANY lifetime for objects instantiated like this...

Comment: @mgilson That breaks object instantiation (type invocation). See this paste: http://pastebin.com/DvBC0qay

Comment: @Marcin -- Yeah, you need to remove `self` from the argument list in that case as well.  ( e.g. `def __init__(): print "bar"` )

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your class is called `Foo` you can just do the following:

```
Foo()
```

However if you need to do this, it could be a sign that you need to rethink your design.

Comment: This is likely to call `__new__` that will call `__init__`, right?

Comment: Does `__new__` actually call `__init__`, or does that happen after `__new__` returns the new instance?

Comment: Even if `__new__` has to wait for an instance before calling `__init__`, this will still work. `__new__` and `__init__` will be called and the result of the two will not be assigned to a variable in memory